# Inclusion- exclusion, Probability set theory

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

**Inclusion-Exclusion:**  For any two events $A$ and $B$, $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$.

I know that $$P(A \cup B) = \frac{|A \cup B|}{\Omega} = \frac{|A \cap B^c| + |B \cap A^c| + |A \cap B|}{\Omega}$$
but I keep getting plus $P(A \cap B)$ instead of the subtraction as the last term.

Comment: Both equations are correct because theiy use different first two terms.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: I inferred from your work that you were trying to prove the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle for two sets.  However, you should have said this explicitly in your question so that readers do not have to guess what your question is.

Answer (score 1):

It is true that
$$|A \cup B| = |A \cap B^C| + |A \cap B| + |A^C \cap B| \tag{1}$$
since the disjoint union of the three sets on the right-hand side (RHS) is the set $A \cup B$.  Notice also that
$$|A| = |A \cap B^C| + |A \cap B| \tag{2}$$
since the disjoint union of the two sets on the RHS of equation $2$ is the set $A$ and that
$$|B| = |A \cap B| + |A^C \cap B| \tag{3}$$
since the disjoint union of the two sets on the RHS of equation $3$ is the set $B$.  Therefore, if we add and subtract the term $|A \cap B|$ to equation $1$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
|A \cup B| & = |A \cap B^C| + |A \cap B| + |A^C \cap B| + |A \cap B| - |A \cap B|\\
           & = |A| + |B| - |A \cap B|
\end{align*}
as required.

Hence,
\begin{align*}
\Pr(A \cup B) & = \frac{|A \cup B|}{|\Omega|}\\
              & = \frac{|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|}{|\Omega|}\\
              & = \frac{|A|}{|\Omega|} + \frac{|B|}{|\Omega|} - \frac{|A \cap B|}{|\Omega|}\\
              & = \Pr(A) + \Pr(B) - \Pr(A \cap B)
\end{align*}